# What does the Yoast Cornerstone Content feature do?

Tags: seo, wordpress, content, yoast

In Yoast for WordPress I noticed an option for "cornerstone content" and I have switched it on. However in the HTML code generated of the designated page I do not see any difference.

What exactly is this functionality doing?
And is it important to use this feature?

Comment: Did you start with the documentation? https://yoast.com/what-is-cornerstone-content/

Comment: Yes I did. But I do not see any HTML changes when this has been enabled. Since it is a switch in Yoast. Mark this page as cornerstone content.

Comment: Why are you expecting HTML changes?  From their documentation I would expect to see extra links to the page, or suggestions of where you could create extra links to the page.

Comment: Well I expected HTML changes or at least something. But nothing is really happening when I select this option. Neither suggestions. Neither extra links etc etc.